# Android NFC Write NFCA tag

Tags: java, android, tags, nfc

I've a problem when I try to write a NFC A tag on Android 2.3.6 (nexus S). I use the code from this example:
http://www.jessechen.net/blog/how-to-nfc-on-the-android-platform/

More precisely, when I do the Ndef.get(mytag) I get null so I cannot write my tag.

Here is the code from which I get a null references (the 'tag' value is not null), only the ndef.

```
Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag); 

if (ndef != null) {
    ndef.connect();
    if (!ndef.isWritable()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (ndef.getMaxSize() < size) {
        return false;
    }
    ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);
    return true;
}
```

Thank you for you help !!!

Answer (score 2):

Your tag may not yet be formatted for NDEF message storage or may not be able to store NDEF messages at all.
Check whether `NdefFormatable.get(tag)` returns something unequal to `null`.

Then use `NdefFormatable.format(message)` to try to write your message.

If `NdefFormatable.get(tag)` returns `null`, then either Android has no means to format  the tag or the tag is incompatible to NDEF storage.
(Alternatively, you may want to use TagWriter, https://market.android.com/details?id=com.nxp.nfc.tagwriter to format and write your tag.)

Answer (score 0):

Try NfcA.get(tag) instead. Not sure why you are getting the error though, but trying the other class might work.